# Prevent event bubbling in Vue

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, event-bubbling, event-propagation

```
<div id="largeArea" v-on:click="do_X">
    <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

So I have this issue in Vue where I don't want `do_X` to trigger when I click on the button, although its a part of the `largeArea`.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers), use the `self` event modifier to only capture events originating on the element itself.

```
<div id="largeArea" v-on:click.self="do_X">
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    do_X () {
      console.log(Date.now(), 'do_X')
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#largeArea {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id="largeArea" @click.self="do_X">
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there an event decorator I can add to the child element. because I do want event bubbling for every child element except this one other button. {{UPDATE: i used @click.prevent.stop for desired effect! }}

Answer (score 147):

I found that using the 'stop' event modifier on the child element worked for me.
eg

```
<div id="app">
  <div id="largeArea" @click="do_X">
    <button @click.stop="do_Y">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a much better answer as in my case I need to be able to click anywhere on the larger div to perform a specific action, and on clicking on the small element to perform another action. In my case "v-on:click.stop="doSomeAction()" worked.

Comment: @Meanman there's little difference between `stop` on the child and `self` on the parent for isolating the event source. However, the former has a side-effect of preventing the event from reaching lower levels in the document. For example, you could not track all clicks on the `document` or `body` if you use `stop`

Comment: Great, this even worked with a nested `<a>` and without event handler for me: `<a :href="data.link" target="_blank" @click.stop>`

Answer (score 13):

### Prevent bubbling for all clicks inside a container `<div>`

```
<div @click.stop="" class="action">

  <button @click="someClickAction1()">Action 1</button>

  <button @click="someClickAction2()">Action 2</button>

<div>
```

### Prevent bubbling on an existing click action

```
<button @click.stop="someClickAction()">Single Action</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Neither of the provided answers. In my situation it's wrapped in a `<router-link>` not a `<div>`.

I called `e.preventDefault()` on the child element and it worked

```
<router-link>
    <div @click="do_X"></div>
</router-link>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    do_X (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      console.log(Date.now(), 'do_X')
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I was creating a navigation bar and had similar requirements. I wanted the popup menu to be closed when clicked anywhere except on the menu or its children.

This can be done by using event modifiers. Fore reference see this [docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/events.html#event-modifiers)

Specifically, we can use `stop` event modifier.

```
<div id="largeArea" v-on:click="do_X()">
    <button @click.stop="">Button</button>
</div>
```

`.stop` will stop the event propagation.

---

In my case better solution was to use `e.target != this.$el`

```
mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
        if(e.target !== this.$el)
            this.showChild = false;
    })
}
```